# Slicing an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a below statement:

```
print_r($dates);
```

Giving output:

```
Array ( [0] => Fri, Jan 25 [1] => Sat, Jan 26 [2] => Sun, Jan 27)
```

I would like to print the date separately. I know the method of explode, but is there any other method to separate out my date (Fri,Jan25) separately each date.

Comment: why not using functions..

Comment: _"Also I do not want to use functions"_ ...what?

Comment: We understand *what* you're saying... we just don't understand *why*.

Comment: @Parab - Why not go all the way, and just not use a method that uses any PHP at all?

Comment: Do you want to echo dates it only?

Comment: 1. Functions are good. Functions are very good. 2. Have you tried a for(each) loop?

Comment: @Parab : Then simply echo it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use functions then just `echo` it :

```
echo $dates[0];
echo $dates[1];
echo $dates[2];
```

OR

use `foreach loop` :

```
foreach($dates as $d)
   echo "Date : " . $d . "<br>";
```

Comment: Hi Ultimate, Thanks thatz what i was required!! CHEERS!!

Comment: @Parab : U R Welcome.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not functions? They are great =)

```
foreach($dates as $date){
    $arr_dates = explode(",", $date);
    echo 'day is '.$arr_dates[0].' and date is '.$arr_dates[1]."\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
$pattern = '/(\w+), (\w+) (\d+)/i';
foreach($dates as $dt){ 
    if(preg_match($pattern, $dt, $matches)){
        echo 'DoW : '.$matches[1].'<br>';
        echo 'Mon : '.$matches[2].'<br>';
        echo 'Day : '.$matches[3].'<br>';
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($dates as $val){
   echo $val;
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`strtotime`**](http://php.net/strtotime) to parse dates so that you can get meaningful information about each date.  Then you can use the [**`date`**](http://php.net/date) function to display in whatever format you like (or [**`getdate`**](http://php.net/getdate) to get details about day, month, year, etc.):

```
$dates = Array ("Fri, Jan 25", "Sat, Jan 26", "Sun, Jan 27");
foreach($dates as $datestr) {
    $date = strtotime($datestr);
    echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $date)."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Friday 25th of January 2013 12:00:00 AM
Saturday 26th of January 2013 12:00:00 AM
Sunday 27th of January 2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/6xeCxt

There are a lot of [date/time manipulation functions](http://php.net/ref.datetime.php) built-in to PHP that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $array = array("Fri, Jan 25", "Sat, Jan 26", "Sun, Jan 27");
 foreach($array as $date) {
   $dateStr = substr($date, 4); 
  echo $dateStr;
 }
?>
```